# Oracle query - Need result of last 10 weeks product detail

Tags: oracle

I need oracle query for last 10 week data from below list. I want to fetch top 10 week date from the below list

```
wk Date     ProductName  cnt
(Monday dt)
06/22/20    A            10
06/22/20    B            20
06/22/20    C            15
06/15/20    A            10
06/15/20    B            20
06/08/20    D            30
06/08/20    E            20
06/01/20    A            10
06/01/20    E            10
.
.
.
```

Comment: It seems to me you contradict yourself. First you say you want the "last 10 weeks".  But then you say you want the "top 10". What is the criteria for "top 10"?  The largest values in the CNT column?   What if the largest CNT was more than 10 weeks ago? Or do you simply want the last 10 weeks, ordered by CNT?  You need to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an query for this like to achive your required output.

```
select ilv.* from(

select product_name, date, cnt  from tab1 
where date> sysdate-70
order by cnt desc)ilv
where rownum<10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CNT DESC NULLS LAST) AS RN 
FROM YOUR_TABLE T
WHERE WK_DATE BETWEEN NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 1, 'MONDAY') - INTERVAL '70' DAY 
              AND NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 1, 'MONDAY'))
WHERE RN <= 10;
```